# Unable to run emacs in `magit-status-mode` with using custom initialization file

Tags: emacs, boot, magit

I like to use terminal tools and the one of them is '***magit***' - awesome Git client implemented as an Emacs package. I use it to control Git projects. I have a script which automatically start emacs at computer boot (this same me a time with routine work). **But also I'm looking for a way to run *emacs* in *magit-status* mode** (without manual executing `M-x magit-status...` each time). Emacs provide a possibility to configure it's environment in init configuration file. To make emacs run magit at boot I created special `magit.el` file and run emacs from command line

```
$ emacs -q --load ~/.emacs.d/magit.el
```

Unfortunately I unable to switch emacs in `magic-status-mode` - something wrong with init file. Emacs remains in `lisp-interaction-mode` after boot. The content of init file is below:

```
;; disable welcome screen at launch
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)

(setq visible-bell t)

; Disable tabs indent
(setq-default c-basic-offset 4
          tab-width 4
          indent-tabs-mode nil)

(global-set-key "\C-h" 'delete-backward-char)

;; Makes *scratch* empty.
(setq initial-scratch-message "")

;; Removes *scratch* from buffer after the mode has been set.
(defun remove-scratch-buffer ()
  (if (get-buffer "*scratch*")
      (kill-buffer "*scratch*")))
;(add-hook 'after-change-major-mode-hook 'remove-scratch-buffer)

;; Removes *messages* from the buffer.
;(setq-default message-log-max nil)
;(kill-buffer "*Messages*")

;; Removes *Completions* from buffer after you've opened a file.
;(add-hook 'minibuffer-exit-hook
;      '(lambda ()
;         (let ((buffer "*Completions*"))
;           (and (get-buffer buffer)
;                (kill-buffer buffer)))))

;; Don't show *Buffer list* when opening multiple files at the same time.
(setq inhibit-startup-buffer-menu t)

;; Show only one active window when opening multiple files at the same time.
;(add-hook 'window-setup-hook 'delete-other-windows)

;; Tell emacs where is your personal elisp lib dir (magit)
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/") 
(load "git") ;; best not to include the ending “.el” or “.elc”
;; activate installed packages
(package-initialize) 


(setq-default major-mode 'magit-status-mode)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'magit-status-mode)
(if after-init-time
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'magit-status-mode))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```el
(call-interactively 'magit-status)
```

Instead of all of this:

```el
(setq-default major-mode 'magit-status-mode)
(add-hook 'after-init-hook #'magit-status-mode)
(if after-init-time
  (add-hook 'after-init-hook #'magit-status-mode))
```

Using `after-init-hook` would make sense in an init file, but with `-q` you're explicitly *not* using an init file (using `--load` is not the same thing), and that hook has already run by the time your custom `magit.el` file is loaded, so nothing you add to the hook at that stage will ever be processed.

Note that you *don't* want to call `magit-status-mode` at all. That's not a major mode you would ever be expected to invoke manually, as you would never want that mode for any buffer other than the one created by the `magit-status` command.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!